# How to remove space after wrapped text using display:flex?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make two block of texts side by side. I am using display:flex with flex-direction: flex-start, however, sometimes there is a large gap between two blocks when I change the page size.

Case 1:
[when the page width is small, there is no space:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nfMn.png)

Case 2: [while enlarging the page width, the second block move to right and there comes a gap between two blocks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKR5d.png)

Case 3: [when the page is large enough for fitting the long word, the gap close again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmcrs.png)

Here is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

.a {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: flex-start;
   flex-flow: row;
   align-content: flex-start;
}

.b {
   border: 1px solid;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>


<div class="a">
  <div class="b">This is some text. This is some texts a very loooooooooooooong text</div>
  <div class="b">This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide your code please?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To get accurate answers is recommended to write exactly what are you trying to achieve, attach the portion of code interested and also explain what you've tried.

Comment: I posted the question too quickly. Added the code.

Comment: you cannot do this